# OpenCV On VS10 opens then closes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I just started using opencv 2.4.0. So after installing, I tried to copy a sample code from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) to my project. So click on F5 then a cmd screen opens then closes immediately. I tried googling but didnt find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go cmd, and go exe's directory, but before find a video file, copy it to that working directory too.

```
cd WhereYourApplicationExe
yourapplication.exe avideofile.wmv avideofile.wmv 10 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a console application, you can either add

```
cin.get();
return 0;
```

in your `Main` block. This ensures that the prompt window will wait for user input before closing as, at the moment, the code is executed and the command prompt window is closed upon completion.

Alternatively, if you don't need the debugger, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to run it.

Comment: It just stops the cmd from closing. The windows that are suppose to open does open like in the link:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If the windows are opening as expected and you don't want to keep the cmd from closing, what's the problem? If you're running a console application the cmd prompt will have to run at one point, even if it's opening external windows.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant to say was when i press F5 to run it, the cmd opens then close but and the nothing happens.

Comment: Is it the same if you press `CTRL + F5`?

Comment: CTRL + F5 works! But now on the cmd it displays "Not enough parameters". Did i forget to copy anything else?

Comment: I don't know what you've copied but from the error message I'm guessing that you haven't supplied any command line arguments. Scroll to the bottom of that tutorial and follow those steps to see how to include the correct parameters.